# Is there a way to ask for an input using the schedule module in python?

Tags: python

I am a new user of python and I am really just trying to get a feel for the language. Currently, I am trying to build a python script that will open all of my class links at a certain time using the schedule module. I want to be able to ask the user when they want to open that link but I am not sure how to get input and use what the user gave to the computer to open that URL at that time. I am able to get the URL to open but not able to open it at a specific time. Does anyone know if this is possible?
I have attached the code below and bolded the specific block

```
import webbrowser
import schedule

import time

url = input("Enter your url: ")

day1 = input("Enter the day: ")

time = input("Enter the time: ")

do = input("Do you want to start at " + day1 +  time)

def open():

    webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)

schedule.every().day1.at('time').do(open)
```

Comment: Maybe you want to look at the the [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html). It contains date and time related stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Since the schedule package doesn't offer an interface to schedule jobs with > days recurrence rule. You should do something like this as a hack to schedule for specific day.

```
import webbrowser
import schedule

import time

from datetime import date

url = input("Enter your url: ")

# accept month & day as numbers
month = int(input("Enter the month (1-12): "))
day = int(input("Enter the day (1-31):"))

time = input("Enter the time: ")

def open():
    today = date.today()
    if today.month == month and today.day == day:
        # do your work here
        webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)

schedule.every().day.at(time).do(open)
```